# How to use Nodejs and Ruby on Rails together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, architecture

I really like Ruby on Rails but I have also developed in node js. Currently I'm making a web app which has chat functionality that could have 30 people in it. For that I want to use node js.

I have never done this,  I'm confused on how's traffic divided between app. How is the state shared between apps for example how would I share the user session will I have to hit the database for every request.

Answer (score 2):

My first recommendation is to not split a web app between two separate server platforms. It overly complicates the project and isn't necessary at all.

That being said, if it must be done, you could use one of the platforms as the 'main' one and the other one for API endpoints stationed at `localhost:some-port-number`. This way, if you were in the main platform (Rails let's say), you could request data via the `node.js` API by redirecting it to whatever IP address (make it a local IP) that node is running on.

Again, I recommend against this. But that's one solution if it must be done.

Comment: What are some complications?

Comment: For the developer, it would complicate the project to use two platforms that do (roughly, not meaning to start a debate) the same thing. They're both server side, they're both handling requests and serving up responses. You only need one of those to do that job. Keeping some URL's in the main project and sending some URL's is an issue. And sharing data models would be another issue, and would unnecessarily complicate it to find workarounds for it.